# How can I check how many times an element was created and create it n number of times

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to create an element(Parameter) n number of times. I used the following method to create an element "Parameter" which contain the value from the Split template. Each recursion create the element "Parameter". How can I check how many time was the element "Parameter" created and and if it was less than n then how can I create it n number of times with no values.

```
<xsl:call-template name="Split">
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="Set string &quot;{attribute}&quot; value &quot;{stringValue}&quot;" />
</xsl:call-template>

    

<xsl:template name="Split">
<xsl:param name="text" select="''" />

<xsl:variable name="tag"  select="substring-before(substring-after($text, '&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
<xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring-after($text, '&quot;')" />


<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$tag != ''">
<xsl:element name = "Paramter">
<xsl:value-of select = "$tag"/>
</xsl:element>

<!--recursive step start: process the remainder of the string -->
<xsl:call-template name="Split">
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="$tail" />
</xsl:call-template>                
<!--recursive step end: process the remainder of the string -->

</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

the Output (for n=9) should look something like this,

```
<Parameter>attribute</Parameter>
<Parameter>value</Parameter>
<Parameter>StringValue</Parameter>
<Parameter></Parameter>
<Parameter></Parameter>
<Parameter></Parameter>
<Parameter></Parameter>
<Parameter></Parameter>
<Parameter></Parameter>
```

Comment: Where does `n=9` come from? I don't see it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the template like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="Split">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'Set string &quot;{attribute}&quot; value &quot;{stringValue}&quot;'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="n" select="9" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

and adjust it so:

```
<xsl:template name="Split">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:if test="$n > 0">
        <Parameter>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text, '&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
        </Parameter>
        <!--recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="Split">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&quot;')" />
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>        
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Then the result will be:

```
<Parameter>{attribute}</Parameter>
<Parameter> value </Parameter>
<Parameter>{stringValue}</Parameter>
<Parameter/>
<Parameter/>
<Parameter/>
<Parameter/>
<Parameter/>
<Parameter/>
```

Note that this exits after 9 iterations. If the string has more than 9 tokens, only the first 9 will appear in the output.